# Auto Resizing Cells in a Table?

Tags: tables, wrap, text

I essentially want my text to wrap in the 3rd columns of my table. With what I have right now the texts keep going, through my table and off the right side of the document. Here is my code.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Item} & \textbf{Due} & \textbf{Specifics and Owner}                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
\\ \hline
Progress Report 1 & 2/15 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Preprocess data. Create simple neural network as proof of concept.\\ Owners: Group Effort\end{tabular}                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
Progress Report 2 & 3/15 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}First implementation of working neural network x-ray classifier. Includes any improvement over randomly classifying data.\\ Owners: Group Effort\end{tabular}                                                            \\ \hline
Preliminary Writeup & 4/12 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Strong improvement in classification by supervising neural network weight selection. \\ Owners: Group Effort\end{tabular}                                                                                                \\ \hline
Final Oral Presentation \& Report & 4/24 - 4/26  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Finished product that is demonstrable. Possibly a final push to see improvements over Preliminary Writeup results. Make sure there is a group understanding of all applied concepts.\\ Owners: Group Effort\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

An image of what currently happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPwzO.jpg

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a compilable minimal working example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` even in simple cases like this.

Answer (score 5):

Please always provide a compilable minimal working example!

You don’t need the nested tables. The `X` column of `tabularx` already wraps text. In order to put a line break within cells in the `X` column, put `\newline` instead of `\\` (which would initiate a new table row).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
%\centering   % see Mico's comment
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Item} & \textbf{Due} & \textbf{Specifics and Owner} \\ \hline
Progress Report 1 & 2/15 & Preprocess data. Create simple neural network as proof of concept.\newline Owners: Group Effort \\ \hline
Progress Report 2 & 3/15 & First implementation of working neural network x-ray classifier. Includes any improvement over randomly classifying data.\newline Owners: Group Effort \\ \hline
Preliminary Writeup & 4/12 & Strong improvement in classification by supervising neural network weight selection. \newline Owners: Group Effort \\ \hline
Final Oral Presentation \& Report & 4/24--4/26 & Finished product that is demonstrable. Possibly a final push to see improvements over Preliminary Writeup results. Make sure there is a group understanding of all applied concepts.\newline Owners: Group Effort \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

---

**Edit:**

Another version using `booktabs` and `\RaggedRight` as proposed by several comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
%\centering   % see Mico's comment
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l l >{\RaggedRight}X}
\toprule
\textbf{Item} & \textbf{Due} & \textbf{Specifics and Owner} \\ \midrule
Progress Report 1 & 2/15 & Preprocess data. Create simple neural network as proof of concept.\newline Owners: Group Effort \\ \midrule
Progress Report 2 & 3/15 & First implementation of working neural network x-ray classifier. Includes any improvement over randomly classifying data.\newline Owners: Group Effort \\ \midrule
Preliminary Writeup & 4/12 & Strong improvement in classification by supervising neural network weight selection. \newline Owners: Group Effort \\ \midrule
Final Oral Presentation \& Report & 4/24--4/26 & Finished product that is demonstrable. Possibly a final push to see improvements over Preliminary Writeup results. Make sure there is a group understanding of all applied concepts.\newline Owners: Group Effort \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. To avoid any large (and unsightly) interword gaps in the third column, one could (a) load the `ragged2e` package and (b) change `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|}` to `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|>{\RaggedRight}X|}`. This will typeset the material in the third column in ragged-right mode rather than  fully-justified mode, while still permitting hyphenation of long words; in contrast, the basic `\raggedright` directive suppresses hyphenation. A separate comment: Since the width of the `tabularx` environment is set to `\textwidth`, `\centering` has no effect and may be omitted.

Comment: i would suggest to op to use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright}X|l|>{\RaggedRight}X|}` with  load the `ragged2e`  package in document preamble.